# Kendo Grid with Angular 2+ Save column Order

Tags: kendo-grid, angular2-forms

I am using kendo-grid in Angular 2+. I want to maintain user column re-ordering for future use. Means, if user change column sequence using drag and drop. He will get Column sequence in same way like last time.

To achieve this, I have to save column Index when user drag and drop Column. And, also to load grid in same sequence like last time.

Any Demo or suggestion would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the following how-to from the docs:

[DOCS](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/how-to/persist-state/)

Note that you will need to run the demos in a separate window from the Plunkers so that you have access to localStorage:

[image]